# Two fixed sidebars

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a simple interface with 2 fixed sidebars on both sides. Below is what I got so far, but sidebar-right is not on the right, how can I fix it? And how can I hide sidebar-right (`display: none`) when screen is <1200px ?

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar-left {
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.sidebar-right {
  transition: all 1s;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.content {
  width: calc(100% - 600px);
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 250px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .sidebar-right {
    display: none;
  }
  .content {
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="sidebar-left">
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">

    <p>

      Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem
      <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem
      <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br>
    </p>

  </div>

  <div class="sidebar-right">
    <p>a</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified Answer

```
.main {
        width: 80%;
     height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.sidebar-left {
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: blue;
 }

 .content {
   float: left;
 width: 200px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: green;
 }

 .sidebar-right {
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: yellow;
 }
```

Use your HTML code along with these classes.

Comment: ur code dont works :(

Comment: Check if this works.

Answer (score 0):

To have your side bars on each side try the following:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.sidebar-right {
  transition: all 1s;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
 background-color: blue;
}

.content {
  width: calc(100% - 600px);
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 250px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .sidebar-right {
    display: none;
  }
  .content {
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4j6r5w0k/

Comment: not works bro :(

Comment: try now, I updated with more of your css

Comment: in ur fiddle both sides arent fixed

Comment: if you want fixed sides, and only for the right one to transition away at < 1200 try : https://jsfiddle.net/91grLbes/ it is using all the same css, with only change from display to opacity on transition

Comment: yes, in original code i have that, but i want to fixed both sides

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q5Ljwn90/ here you go, both sides are fixed and I changed the colours to be more clear